# MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException using ServiceStack ORMLite

Tags: mysql, docker, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I am working with ServiceStack evaluating the ORMLite provider with MySql for use on a.NET Core 1.1 project. I am running into a curious issue I am not sure what the problem is and looking for some guidance on how to troubleshoot this further or possible fixes.

I am running the .Net Core app in a standard docker container and MySql in the standard MySql container. I have been able to successfully run MySQL and connect with the workbench tool.

What I cannot do is get the executing code of the web application to successfully connect to the MySQL container. I have tried various combinations. Those where the IP Address or hostname were wrong I received a meaningful error saying the host was unknown.

But under scenarios where server name or IP address values that are used that are appropriate for the MySQL container, I receive a generic MySQLException error. The username and password are correct. I have even used the root account to ensure that there aren't any potential security hangups.

Here is a code snippet of where I am attempting to connect. This setup was working well using a local SQL db file,  there is just something I am missing with either the configuration of Docker or MySQL that I haven't been able to isolate.

```
    const string connectionString = "Server=3400f112c973:3306;Database=ServiceDB;Uid=root;Pwd=my-secret-pw;";
        container.Register<IDbConnectionFactory>(
            new OrmLiteConnectionFactory(connectionString, MySqlDialect.Provider ));

        using (var db = container.Resolve<IDbConnectionFactory>().Open())
        {
            if (db.CreateTableIfNotExists<TypeExample>())
            {
                //Add seed data
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

I have figured out my scenario.

In the MySQL Connection string, if you are using a non-standard port, you need to use the port parameter to specify the different port and omit the port entirely if using the standard port.

My issue was I was always using "Server=*servername*:*port*;" which is an incorrect format and should have been "Server=*servername*;Port=*port*;" in the cases where I was using a nonstandard port number, otherwise Port= can be omitted.